# PHP CodeIgniter DB get array of affected row id's

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Is it possible to get the array of affected rows after the query? `$this->db->affected_rows()` can return a total number, but what I need is an array of all the id's affected. Is it possible? My query looks like:

```
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $notEditableIds)
         ->where($key, $oldValue)
         ->or_where($key, NULL)
         ->update('fields', array($key => $value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the targeted row before update :-

```
$result=$this->db->select('id')
     ->from('table_name')
     ->where_not_in('id', $notEditableIds)
     ->where($key, $oldValue)
     ->or_where($key, NULL)->result_array();
$this->db->where_not_in('id', $notEditableIds)
         ->where($key, $oldValue)
         ->or_where($key, NULL)
         ->update('fields', array($key => $value));
if($this->db->affected_rows()){
   return $result;
}
 else{
 return []; 
}
```